# cant sort the following tree map

Tags: java, loops, treeset

```
for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {
  Map<Double,String> m = new HashMap<Double,String>();

  String pre = "abc";
  String post = ".txt";
  for (int ii = 0; ii < 11; ii++) {
    m.put(similarityScore[a],pre + a + post + '\n');
  }
  SortedSet<Double> set = new TreeSet<Double>(m.keySet());
  for (Double d : set) {
    System.out.println(d + " " + m.get(d));
  }
}
```

Output :

```
0.5773502691896258 abc0.txt
0.5773502691896258 abc1.txt
0.5773502691896258 abc2.txt
NaN abc3.txt
0.5773502691896258 abc4.txt
NaN abc5.txt
NaN abc6.txt
NaN abc7.txt
NaN abc8.txt
0.5773502691896258 abc9.txt
NaN abc10.txt
```

This code should be able to sort the double values. But it displays the output on top. What happen ?

Comment: I suggest you eliminate the NaN values (Not a Number). Try replacing them with zero or -1.

Comment: hi, do you know how could i replace them ? I am new towards this type of values. I was shocked on getting this value.

Comment: Your title talks about "tree map", but your implementation uses a hash map. And hash maps usually don't provide any sorting. Despite the NaNs, what else would you expect to be different in your output? All your double are either the same or NaN. Therefore, I'd say the output is sorted.

Comment: assign similarityScore[a] to a local variable, then test the local variable with Double.isNaN(). if true, then replace the local variable with a default value such as 0 or -1, and put the local variable into the map instead of similarityScore[a]. But it looks like some other folks have spotted other issues further down that need to be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost certainly `NaN`.

This is, as the name suggests, not a realy number, and behaves very strangely in terms of comparisons.  Is `NaN` greater than, equal to, or less than `0.5773502691896258`?  It could be any of those results, and isn't even required to be consistent within a single execution of the program.  `NaN` is not even equal to itself, which says something about how preconceptions of the laws of equality, and strong ordering, go out of the window when `NaN` is involved.

So the fix is not to use a non-numeric and expect `Double.compareTo()` to do what you want with it.  Depending on what `NaN` *means* when returned from `similarityScore()`, there are several approaches you could take.  If it means that it's not a match at all, you could have that method return a `Double` (rather than a `double`), return `null` in these cases, and then only add non-null results to the map.  If these results should be displayed anyway, then perhaps you could use a result of `0.0` or `-1.0`, assuming that's less than any "real" similarity score.  If you want something more finessed, then returning something as pure and straightforward as a primitive double is likely going to be the problem, and you may need to return your own (simple) domain class instead.

---

As an aside - why on earth do you create and populate a `HashMap`, then use a `TreeSet` to get the iteration order over the keys?  If you simply create `m` as a `TreeMap<Double, String> you get exactly the iteration order you want, so can just iterate over`m.entrySet()`.  It's clearer, more idiomatic (thus more understandable), and more efficient, so there's no reason not to do this.

Comment: The problem isn't primarily `NaN`, it's broken logic :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 11; ii++) {
    m.put(similarityScore[a],pre + a + post + '\n');
}
```

This puts the same value into the map 11 times - you're not referencing ii inside the loop.

```
for (Double d : set) {
    System.out.println(d + " " + m.get(d));
}
```

This prints the single entry in the map.

You do the above for values `0..filename` - Adding a value to the map several times, then printing it and restarting with a new map.

```
Map<Double,String> m = new HashMap<Double,String>();
for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {
  String pre = "abc";
  String post = ".txt";
  m.put(similarityScore[a],pre + a + post + '\n');
}
SortedSet<Double> set = new TreeSet<Double>(m.keySet());
for (Double d : set) {
  System.out.println(d + " " + m.get(d));
}
```

This creates a map, populates it with values for `0..filename`, then prints it sorted. You'll still have issues with `NaN` which isn't really sortable.

```
Map<Double,String> m = new TreeMap<Double,String>();
for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {
  String pre = "abc";
  String post = ".txt";
  m.put(similarityScore[a],pre + a + post + '\n');
}
for (Double d : m.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(d + " " + m.get(d));
}
```

And this uses a `TreeMap` - No need for the intermediate `Set`

Answer (score 0):

For any Collection to sort, the type of the value on which you are sorting should be same. And should implement comparable interface.

In your case you have NaN and Double values to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop means you're sorting for each filename separately.  You'll need to pull the sorting out of the loop to get those values sorted.  (Ooops, @Eric beat me to it.)

Comment: It was meant to. I need the sorted values to be paired together with their individual filenames after the sorting process.